# My jTree does not show the nodes

Tags: java, jscrollpane, jtree

i am working with jTree and when i set the model, the jTree does not show the changes, the code is the next

```
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Main() {
        initComponents();
        treeExample();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {
       ...
    }

    public void treeExample(){
       DefaultMutableTreeNode top =
        new DefaultMutableTreeNode("The Java Series");
        createNodes(top);
        jTree1 = new JTree(top);
        jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(jTree1);  
    }
private void createNodes(DefaultMutableTreeNode top) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode category = null;
    DefaultMutableTreeNode book = null;

    category = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Books for Java Programmers");
    top.add(category);

    book = new DefaultMutableTreeNode
       ("The Java Tutorial: A Short Course on the Basics");
    category.add(book);

}
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTree jTree1;
}
```

I am usig the desing mode directly,What could be the problem?

Comment: Recommend posting an [mcve]. What can be guessed based upon the posted code: presuming `initComponents` constructs your UI, it is called before `treeExample` in which you create new UI components without adding them to the UI

Comment: i try to call first the teeExample before that initComponents and is the same :/

Comment: All Swing components must be created and manipulated in the AWT event dispatch thread.  JTree is particularly sensitive to this.  Are you creating an instance of your `Main` class in the event dispatch thread?